# Async calls causing information to be displayed before it is loaded

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem where information from a JSON file is being loaded after  the function is completed to display it to the browser in JavaScript. I've been studying [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) that explains how to get around the problem, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this without the use of JQuery. I know JQuesry would be the better way to do it, unfortunately I'm constrained to only using JavaScript.

First I get the JSON information:

```
// Generic Function to get JSON data
    this.getJSON = function (url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                callback(null, xhr.response);
            } else {
                callback(status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

Then I put it into a JavaScript object:

```
this.GetQuiz = function () {
        var thisQuiz = this;
        // Get the extract the quiz from the JSON folder
        app.getJSON('json/demo.json', function(err, data) {
            if (err != null) { // If there's a problem
                // Add a debug for getting the quiz JSON
                console.log('Unable to load quiz: ' + err);
            } else {
                // Load the quiz into the quiz base
                this.Title = data.title;
                this.Introduction = data.longtitle;
                this.HeroImage = imgBase + 'products/' + data.img;
                this.About = data.extra;
                // Set How To Play
                if(this.Type == 'Knowledge') { // Knowledge Quiz
                    this.HowToPlayText = "Knowledge, how to play text...";
                } else if (this.Type == 'Identity') { // Identity Quiz
                    this.HowToPlayText = "Identity, how to play text...";
                } else if (this.Type == 'TrueFalse') { // TrueFalse Quiz
                    this.HowToPlayText = "True/false, how to play text...";
                }
                // Make sure we can see what we are loading if nothing displays
                console.log('We are loading the quiz for the ' + this.Title + ' range');
                // Load Questions
                thisQuiz.GetQuestions();
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);
```

Then I call a function to display parts of this object to the browser:

```
this.QuizSelection = function () {
        // Fill the ID's with the right info
        app.SetBackground('head', this.HeroImage);
        console.log('1 ' + this.HeroImage);
        app.LoadInnerHTML('breadcrumbs', 'Home / ' + this.Title);
        app.LoadInnerHTML('quizSelectionTitle',this.Title);
        console.log('2 ' + this.Title);
        app.LoadInnerHTML('quizSelectionIntro',this.Introduction);
        console.log('3 ' + this.Introduction);
        // Show the Quiz Selection and Heading
        app.ShowSection('head');
        app.ShowSection('quizSelection');
        console.log('Quiz Selection');
    }.bind(this);
```

This is all wrapped into two functions that I call as the page loads:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var quiz = new QuizBase('Knowledge', 'Product');
    quiz.GetQuiz();
    quiz.QuizSelection();
}
```

I basically need a way to run `quiz.QuizSelection();` after `quiz.GetQuiz();` completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make it possible to pass a callback function as an argument of `GetQuiz`

```
this.GetQuiz = function (callback) {
  ...
}
```

And then inside the callback of `getJSON()`, right after checking for `if (err != null)` in the folling `else` block, check if *your* callback is set and if so, call it:

```
if (typeof callback === 'function')  {
  callback();
}
// or a shorter way of doing this:
callback && callback();
```

Then you can just use

```
quiz.GetQuiz(quiz.QuizSelection);
```

to achieve the desired order.

You might have to do the same with your `thisQuiz.GetQuestions()` method, if that also has to happen before `QuizSelection()` can be run. So you would just pass on the callback from `quiz.GetQuiz()` to `thisQuiz.GetQuestions()`.

Comment: Thanks - where would 'inside the callback of getJSON()' be? Is that in the success part? So if it manages to get the JSON?

Comment: Right, sorry, that was a bit ambiguous. Exactly, that is also a callback function. And inside that, after you check for `if (err != null)`, in the `else` block, is where you check for and execute *your* callback function.